# How to make jquery script work after Ajax dom append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Ye, i know about "on" method and most of answers here about "on" are not specific. Can someone help me with this code?

```
$(function(){

var pagePositon = 0,
    sectionsSeclector = 'article#sector',
    $scrollItems = $(sectionsSeclector),
    offsetTolorence = 30,
    pageMaxPosition = $scrollItems.length - 1;

//Map the sections:

$scrollItems.each(function(index,ele) { $(ele).attr("debog",index).data("pos",index); });

// Bind to scroll
$(window).bind('scroll',upPos);

//Move on click:
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 100 && pagePositon+1 <= pageMaxPosition) {
        pagePositon++;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
              scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top
        }, 300);
    }
    if (e.which == 97 && pagePositon-1 >= 0) {
        pagePositon--;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
              scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top
          }, 300);
        return false;
    }
});

//Update position func:
function upPos(){
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
   var $cur = null;
    $scrollItems.each(function(index,ele){
        if ($(ele).offset().top < fromTop + offsetTolorence) $cur = $(ele);
    });
   if ($cur != null && pagePositon != $cur.data('pos')) {
       pagePositon = $cur.data('pos');
   }                   
}
});
```

When you press "d" or "a" it goes to next or prev  with id="sector" and that's fine. But occasionally, after Ajax Call and after append of new articles, script can't move to them. I know that they are not binded (after dom refresh) and how to make that script work after Ajax dom change?

Comment: _it goes to next or prev with id="sector"_ Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: You have to update `$scrollItems`. Otherwise it only contains the elements present at the time of assignment.

Comment: i know about it, so i need a obvious example, guys. I cant even google example to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
$(function(){

var pagePositon = 0,
    sectionsSeclector = 'article#sector',
    $scrollItems = $(sectionsSeclector),
    offsetTolorence = 30,
    pageMaxPosition = $scrollItems.length - 1;

//Map the sections:


// Bind to scroll


//Move on click:
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    $scrollItems = $(sectionsSeclector);
    pageMaxPosition = $scrollItems.length - 1;
    $scrollItems.each(function(index,ele) { $(ele).attr("debog",index).data("pos",index); });

     $(window).bind('scroll',upPos);

    if (e.which == 100 && pagePositon+1 <= pageMaxPosition) {
        pagePositon++;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
              scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top
        }, 300);
    }
    if (e.which == 97 && pagePositon-1 >= 0) {
        pagePositon--;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
              scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top
          }, 300);
        return false;
    }
});

//Update position func:
function upPos(){
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
   var $cur = null;
    $scrollItems.each(function(index,ele){
        if ($(ele).offset().top < fromTop + offsetTolorence) $cur = $(ele);
    });
   if ($cur != null && pagePositon != $cur.data('pos')) {
       pagePositon = $cur.data('pos');
   }                   
}
```

});